# Regarding String manipulation

Tags: java, string

I have a String str which can have  list of values like below. I want the first letter in the string to be uppercase and if underscore appears in the string then i need to remove it and need to make the letter after it as upper case. The rest all letter i want it to be lower case.

```
""
"abc" 
"abc_def"
"Abc_def_Ghi12_abd"
"abc__de"
"_"
Output:
""
"Abc"
"AbcDef"
"AbcDefGhi12Abd"
"AbcDe"
""
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice idea ...

Hope you'll succeed without asking one of those beginners questions like "where is the doc for the String class saying all i could want about the methods I need to do my homework".

Comment: So you have *one* string but apparently *four* individual “first” letters in that string?

Comment: This is similar to what Commons Lang WordUtils.capitalize does.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually, it's very similar to another question of that user too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375649/converting-to-upper-and-lower-case-in-java

Comment: I have one String which can one of the above listed values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without showing us that you put *any* effort into this problem this is going to be kinda vague.

I see two possibilities here:

1. Split the string at underscores, apply the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375649/converting-to-upper-and-lower-case-in-java) to each part and re-combine them.
2. Create a `StringBuilder`, walk through the string and keep track of whether you are

   - at the start of the string
   - after an underscore or
   - somewhere else

   and act appropriately on the current character before appending it to the `StringBuilder` instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. replace `_` with space (`str.replace("_", " ")`)
2. use [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str);`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29) (from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/))
3. replace space with nothing (`str.replace(" ", "")`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regexp based code:

```
public static String camelize(String input) {
  char[] c = input.toCharArray();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*_([a-z]).*");
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
  while ( m.find() ) {
    int index = m.start(1);
    c[index] = String.valueOf(c[index]).toUpperCase().charAt(0); 
  }
  return String.valueOf(c).replace("_", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern/Matcher in the java.util.regex package:

for each string that is in your array do the following:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[^|_](\w)").matcher(inStr);
while(match.find()) {
   match.appendReplacement(output, matcher.match(0).ToUpper());
}
match.appendTail(output);

// Will have the properly capitalized string.
String capitalized = output.ToString();
```

The regular expression looks for either the start of the string or an underscore "[^|_]"
Then puts the following character into a group "(\w)"

The code then goes through each of the matches in the input string capitalizing the first satisfying group.