# First char to upper case

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upper case every first letter of word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149855/how-to-upper-case-every-first-letter-of-word-in-a-string)
>   [Most efficient way to make the first character of a String lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052840/most-efficient-way-to-make-the-first-character-of-a-string-lower-case)

I want to convert the first letter of a string to upper case. I am attempting to use replaceFirst() as described in JavaDocs, but I have no idea what is meant by regular expression.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
public static String cap1stChar(String userIdea)
{
    String betterIdea, userIdeaUC;
    char char1;
    userIdeaUC = userIdea.toUpperCase();
    char1 = userIdeaUC.charAt(0);
    betterIdea = userIdea.replaceFirst(char1); 
    return betterIdea;
}//end cap1stChar
```

The compiler error is that the argument lists differ in lengths. I presume that is because the regex is missing, however I don't know what that is exactly.

Comment: `String s = "this is a String"; s= s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);`

Comment: You might want to check
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: This is the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (abbreviated "regex" or "reg-ex") is a string that defines a search pattern.

What `replaceFirst()` does is it uses the regular expression provided in the parameters and replaces the first result from the search with whatever you pass in as the other parameter.

What you want to do is convert the string to an array using the `String` class' [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method, and then use `Character.toUpperCase()` to change the character to upper case (obviously). Your code would look like this:

```
char first = Character.toUpperCase(userIdea.charAt(0));
betterIdea = first + userIdea.substring(1);
```

Or, if you feel comfortable with more complex, one-lined java code:

```
betterIdea = Character.toUpperCase(userIdea.charAt(0)) + userIdea.substring(1);
```

Both of these do the same thing, which is converting the first character of `userIdea` to an upper case character.

Comment: `userIdea.toCharArray()[0]` is an expensive way of doing `userIdea.charAt(0)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't know how I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: StringBuilder class is great companion   suppose name is String    than code =>   if(name.length()>0){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(name);
            if(stringBuilder.length()==1){
                name= String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(stringBuilder.charAt(0)));
            }else{
                name= String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(stringBuilder.charAt(0)))+stringBuilder.substring(1);
            }

        }

Answer (score 41):

Or you can do

```
s = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
```

Comment: Does not work for strings shorter than two characters.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, it works for strings of length 1.

Comment: It doesn't work for strings of length 0

Comment: Why should anyone want to get an uppercase equivalent of the first character of a null string?

Comment: Maybe those who don't want their programs to crash due to unexpected null strings ;-)

Comment: @Dominik Do you mean "unexpected empty strings" ? A `null` is a different situation.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static String cap1stChar(String userIdea)
{
    char[] stringArray = userIdea.toCharArray();
    stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
    return userIdea = new String(stringArray);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Comilation error is due arguments are not properly provided, replaceFirst accepts regx as initial arg. [a-z]{1} will match string of simple alpha characters of length 1.

Try this.

```
betterIdea = userIdea.replaceFirst("[a-z]{1}", userIdea.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String toCamelCase(String string) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string);
    sb.replace(0, 1, string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
userIdeaUC = userIdea.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + userIdea.length() > 1 ? userIdea.substring(1) : "";
```

or

```
userIdeaUC = userIdea.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
if(userIdea.length() > 1)
   userIdeaUC += userIdea.substring(1);
```

Comment: Might want to remove the ternary expression for readability to Matt B.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you wanted to use replaceFirst, try this:

```
public static String cap1stChar(String userIdea)
{
  String betterIdea = userIdea;
  if (userIdea.length() > 0)
  {
    String first = userIdea.substring(0,1);
    betterIdea = userIdea.replaceFirst(first, first.toUpperCase());
  }
  return betterIdea;
}//end cap1stChar
```