# How to auto-capitalise inputted letters in Java

Tags: java

I have a really silly question but I don't know what do since I'm a beginner. From the title, you can probably guess what I need help with...

Here is the basic program I have created:

```
    // Character name.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class name {
    public void charName(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(name + "? That's a very nice name, pleased to meet you!");
    }
}
```

This asks for a name, and then repeats the name again along with a statement. My problem is that this replies with the exact thing I have inputted, so if I enter "jake" it will reply with "jake" or if I enter "JaKe" it will reply with "JaKe". I want this program to be able to say persons name with the first letter capitalised no matter how I type it. E.g. I type "JAKE" but it responds with "Jake".

Comment: When people ask to "show your code" - they don't mean "show all of the code from your program, but nothing about your problem".  In this case, you have shown nothing that even *tries* to convert the case of your string - everything you've shown is irrelevant.

Comment: You can use [WordUtils#capitalizeFully()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some methods of the [`String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

- substring(int, int): Get a substring from and to indices
- substring(int): Get a substring from an index to the end of the string
- toLowerCase(): Convert the entire string to lowercase
- toUpperCase(): Convert the entire string to UPPERCASE

Use both `substring` methods to get the first letter and the rest of the name as separate strings.  Then use `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` and concatenate the strings back together.

Answer (score 2):

One row:

```
    String str = "jake";

    String out = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
```

BTW, as other option  you would use [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html)

`WordUtils.capitalize("i am FINE") = "I Am FINE"`

Answer (score 0):

First lower case the input and then upper case the first char:

```
String name = "Jake";
String lower= name.toLowerCase();
```

After that have a look here: [First char to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464890/first-char-to-upper-case)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
String capSmall = "jAKE";
String firstLetter = String.valueOf(capSmall.charAt(0));
String theRest = capSmall.substring(1);
String result = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + theRest.toLowerCase();
System.out.println("---"+result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Commons library has a nice set of string utilities.

The [`capitalizeFully` method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29) does exactly what you need.

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("pOkEmOn lolz NOOBZ"); // returns Pokemon Lolz Noobz
```

It's true that this solution requires a whole additional dependency but the method handles both single- and multi-word input. Besides, there's a lot of other neat stuff in the library and I literally haven't worked on a project that wouldn't use it.

If you want to stick with vanilla Java API, you can just use

```
name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

This will only work on a single word, though. Some users may be tempted to enter full names like `Bender Bending Rodriguez`. This can be solved easily by combining this with the `split` method but I'm leaving this to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use 3rd party lib. Use this [WordUtils#capitalizeFully(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29). Or if this is homework and you have to do by yourself see [String#toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) and then [String#toUpperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) for the first character, see [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,int%29).