# Need to turn char into lower case and replace it in Java

Tags: java

So I need to make a basic cash register that accepts 5 items in an array with a price on them. Nevertheless, some items will have HST(tax) included with them. To know which items have tax and which don't. The user will press h or H before or after entering the dollar amount. I have got most of the program working, but I cannot get my code to recognize the upper case H to put the tax in it.
Here is my code, Thx in advance for any information:

```
// Import scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

 // Create class and method
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Create scanner object and set scanner variables
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press any key to start");
String key = inp.nextLine();
System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

// Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while loop
int counter = 0;
int index = 0;

// Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
double[] numbers = new double[5];

// Create a boolean variable to use it in the while loop
boolean go = true;

while(go) {           
    String value = inp.nextLine();      
    value.toLowerCase();
    // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
    int indexOfh = value.indexOf('h');
    
    boolean containsh = indexOfh == 0 || indexOfh == (value.length()-1);
    

    if(containsh){ //Validate h at beginning or end
        numbers[index] = Double.parseDouble(value.replace("h", ""));
        index++;
          System.out.println("HST will be taken account for this value");
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter == 5){
      go = false;
    }
}
System.out.println("HST Values:");

for(int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Use `value = value.toLowerCase();`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting to upper and lower case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375649/converting-to-upper-and-lower-case-in-java)

Comment: @wilx oh that works, i was wondering why it wouldn't recognise it as a lowercase, now I realized it was because I  didn't assign it to the variable lol

Comment: @K.Smith yes thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove `indexOfh`  entirely: you can `OR` a bunch of statements together.  This is safe because `>=` is [evaluated before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `||`.

```
// Set the index value to "h" or "H"
boolean containsh = value.indexOf('h') >= 0
    || value.indexOf('H') >= 0;
```

Also, you can make your requirement a little tighter by using `startsWith` and `endsWith` to ignore an 'H' or 'h' in the middle.

```
// Set the index value to "h" or "H"
boolean containsh = value.startsWith("h")
    || value.startsWith("H") || value.endsWith("h")
    || value.endsWith("H");
```

Additionally, you have a resource leak because you never close your `Scanner`: you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to have Java manage this for you.  That, along with a few other simplifications, yields a new version like this.

```
// Import scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

// Create class and method
public class so64283526 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create scanner object and set scanner variables
        try (Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Press any key to start");
            System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of each item");
            System.out.println("Upto 5 inputs are allowed!\n");

            // Initialize counter and index variables to use it in the while
            // loop
            int counter = 0;
            int index = 0;

            // Create a double array variable, and set the limit to 5
            double[] numbers = new double[5];

            while (counter++ < 5) {
                String value = inp.nextLine();
                value.toLowerCase();

                // Set the index value to "h" or "H"
                boolean containsh = value.startsWith("h")
                        || value.startsWith("H") || value.endsWith("h")
                        || value.endsWith("H");

                if (containsh) { // Validate h at beginning or end
                    numbers[index] = Double
                            .parseDouble(value.toLowerCase().replace("h", ""));
                    index++;
                    System.out.println(
                            "HST will be taken account for this value");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("HST Values:");

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Press any key to start

Enter the amount of each item
Upto 5 inputs are allowed!

1
2H
HST will be taken account for this value
H3
HST will be taken account for this value
h4.7
HST will be taken account for this value
5.h6
HST Values:
2.0
3.0
4.7
0.0
0.0
```